# laravel - using if statement correctly

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

My code here is working fine but I need it to be short. I'm using if statement so Select if I will use user_id or Guest_ip.

But I get a long code, any help?

```
if (Auth::guest()) {

        $Task = Enrollee::with('path.ProgrammingField')->with(['path.pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
        {
            $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
              {$q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)->orderBy('id', 'ASC') ->whereDoesntHave('tasktags',
                function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
                            $query->whereNotIn('name', $TagArray);
                        }
                    )
               ->with('tasktags');
           }]
        )->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
       }])
        ->where( 'user_id' , '=' , Auth::user()->id )
        ->where('Path_id', $Path->id) ->get();

        $Tasks = $Task[0]->path;
        $Subs = Enrollee::where( 'user_id' , '=' , Auth::user()->id )->where('Path_id', $Path->id)->get();
       $AllSubs = [];
        foreach($Subs as $sub){
            $AllSubs[] = $sub->task_id;
        }
        $AllSubTasks = implode(" ",$AllSubs);
        $SubTasks = explode(",", ($AllSubTasks));
}

       else {

$Task = Enrollee::
with('path.ProgrammingField')

->with(['path.pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
{
    $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($TagArray)
      {$q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->whereDoesntHave('tasktags',
                function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
                    $query->whereNotIn('name', $TagArray);
                }
            )
       ->with('tasktags');
   }]
)->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
    }])
->where( 'guest_ip' , '=' , '127.0.0.1' )
->where('Path_id', $Path->id) ->get();

$Tasks = $Task[0]->path;
$Subs = Enrollee::where( 'guest_ip' , '=' ,'127.0.0.1') ->where('Path_id', $Path->id)->get();
   $AllSubs = [];
       foreach($Subs as $sub){
            $AllSubs[] = $sub->task_id;
      }
$AllSubTasks = implode(" ",$AllSubs);
$SubTasks = explode(",", ($AllSubTasks));
}
```

Can I Use

```
if (Auth::guest()) {

->where( 'guest_ip' , '=' , '127.0.0.1' )
}
```

I need to be one code and change if I use guest_ip or user id  Using if statement

Comment: this wont help your immediate issue, but properly indenting your code would help you reason about it much easier.

Comment: Thanks but i feel that my code is too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```
$ObjTask = Enrollee::with('path.ProgrammingField')
        ->with(['path.pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {
                $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {
                        $q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
                        ->whereDoesntHave('tasktags', function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
                                    $query->whereNotIn('name', $TagArray);
                                }
                        )
                        ->with('tasktags');
                    }]
                )->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
            }])
        ->where('Path_id', $Path->id);
$Subs = null;
if (Auth::guest()) {
    $Task  = $ObjTask->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();    
    $Subs  = Enrollee::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('Path_id', $Path->id)->get();
}
else {
    $Task  = $ObjTask->where('guest_ip', '=', '127.0.0.1')->get();
    $Subs  = Enrollee::where('guest_ip', '=', '127.0.0.1')->where('Path_id', $Path->id)->get();
}
$Tasks = $Task[0]->path ?? null;
$AllSubs     = [];
$AllSubTasks = $SubTasks    = null;
if (!empty($Subs)) {
    foreach ($Subs as $sub) {
        $AllSubs[] = $sub->task_id;
    }
    $AllSubTasks = implode(" ", $AllSubs);
    $SubTasks    = explode(",", ($AllSubTasks));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After properly indenting the code (like @castis correctly advised) , you can start extracting the bits within the statements into methods. That's called refactoring.

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring):

> Code refactoring is the process of restructuring existing computer code—changing the factoring—without changing its external behavior.

It will look something like this:

```
if(true) {
    doWhateverNeedsToBeDone();
} else {
    doTheOtherThing();
}
```

And you copy all code and paste into the body of these new methods.